# Why isn't my JavaScript working on my wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, yql

Bit of a noob so apology if this is an easy fix and I'm just an idiot..

So I'm trying to get this function to work on my wordpress site..

http://jsfiddle.net/m3h8b/

^ It's a simple function that hits the Yahoo YQL DB and pulls a stock quote and presents it.

I've registered and and enqueued the JS with wordpress like this:

```
wp_register_script( 'stockcatch', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/stockcatch.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1', 'true' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'stockcatch' );
```

and then added this code into my wordpress page in the text section:

```
<input type="text" value="CSCO" id="stockquote" />
<div id="stock"></div>
<button onclick="getprice();">Get price</button>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stockology.ws/wp-content/themes/willow/js/stockcatch.js?ver=1.1'></script>
```

but when I click the get quote button, nothing happens. I also tried adding the entire function within the   for the JS but nothing..

What's the issue?

EDIT: here is the JavaScript I've added to WP..

```
/*
 Catch stock quote from Yahoo! YQL
*/
function getprice()
{


  var symbol = $('#stockquote').val();


var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22"+symbol+"%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json";

$.getJSON(url, function (json)
{

    var lastquote = json.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly;
    $('#stock').text(lastquote);

});
}
```

Comment: Show your whole code.

Comment: What errors are you getting within your console?

Comment: Getting this error within the chrome JS console: uncaught type error: undefined is not a function right under this:

var symbol = $('#stockquote').val();

Comment: @MrJack - i added the javascript to the original post. What else would you guys need to see to make an informed suggestion?

Comment: Wait a sec, do you even include JQuery?

Comment: What happens when you place your code in `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ CODE HERE });`

Comment: @MrJack - isn't that already included when I register the script and put jquery in the array?

Comment: @Darren, nothing happens - same result. it says that the 'var symbol' is undefined but don't quiet know why..any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like 'var symbol = $('#stockquote').val();' is showing up as the issue although I'm not sure why..

Comment: @x7xkayx7x I dont know if its included, you dont show your whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some help from a buddy - thanks for the insight though, guys.

I took my code of:

```
/*
 Catch stock quote from Yahoo! YQL
*/
function getprice()
{


  var symbol = $('#stockquote').val();


var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22"+symbol+"%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json";

$.getJSON(url, function (json)
{

    var lastquote = json.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly;
    $('#stock').text(lastquote);

});
}
```

and changed it to:

/*
     Catch stock quote from Yahoo! YQL
    */
    function getprice()
    {

```
  var symbol = jQuery('#stockquote').val();


var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22"+symbol+"%22)%0A%09%09&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&format=json";

jQuery.getJSON(url, function (json)
{

    var lastquote = json.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly;
    jQuery('#stock').text(lastquote);

});
}
```

effectively removing the $ and replacing with with jQuery - which was causing the error. Now it works!